# How to do load test with real user nearly 10.000 user?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, load, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm planning to do a load test for e-commerce site for valentine's day. I want to do this test with real user. I prepared it Jmeter WebDriver Sampler. I just found blazemeter.com but when i upload my scripts on blazemeter i got errors. I'm waiting a response from them. Do you know any platform, cloud servers provider or anything else to do this?

Comment: http://michaelfarag.blogspot.com.tr/2013/09/load-testing-your-cloud-app-tools_26.html

Comment: look for Jmeter distributed load testing.

Answer (score 2):

There's tons of tools, some of them are;

- https://www.blitz.io/
- http://loadstorm.com/
- https://loader.io/
- https://flood.io/
- http://www.neotys.com/introduction/neoload-cloud-testing.html
- http://www.soasta.com/products/cloudtest/

We work with BlazeMeter, which is easy to use, stable, and its staff are helpful if we stuck at dead-end. It creates nice reports, too.

Comment: Thank you @Turcia. But it seems all of them doing load test with virtual user. Actually I want to do it with real user as Selenium WebDriver.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one more to the mix:

http://loadimpact.com

Also in my 15 years experience of performance and load testing I have very rarely found a need for doing tests with full clients.

The virtual users are much more efficient and scale well in tests even if they possibly need some scripting and data management and reverse engineering of how the service you are testing works on the client.

And running full clients will consume huge amounts of server resources. One client per core in your load generators. Testing an e-commerce site I would estimate requires at least volumes in the thousands.

1.000 test users would require 250 4-core load generators. It quickly becomes large and expensive. For 500 virtual users you can get by with as little as a single 2-core load generator.